# Remove default map objects/text - Google Maps API V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a googleMap with an overlay. But the map always looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove things such as road numbers and city texts. There is no option for this in the map. How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the type of overlay you are using, you can use either GroundOverlay.remove() or TileOverlay.remove() method.

However, if you just want to remove the road numbers and city texts and your overlay image had those elements integrated, to my knowledge its not possible. Unless you use an image that does not have those elements in it already as your overlay image.

You can refer to this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/UrlTileProvider.html) to create a new image URL as a TileProvider for TileOverlay.

Alternatively, if you are using a Ground overlay, refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay#change_an_overlay) to change your overlay image.

Hope it helped. Please let me know if this worked.

Comment: The default Points of interests from Google Maps are laid on top of all overlays (circle, polygons, etc;) that we add programatically.

Comment: @Yozef the question is that he wants to remove the road number/ city text from this overlay (see image). This seems to me like an atlas (or similar) map image embedded on top of the base map provided by Google Maps. Now in that case it is a static image and only option to get rid of those unwanted elements is to replace it.